# Unity Microphone.Start() lag, how to get rid of it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, lag, microphone

Using unity 2020.3 and the XR Plug-in (currently only oculus but will be moving to openxr i hope) and trying to start the microphone when secondary button is pushed. It works but starting the microphone causes lag. Coroutine doens't help, I tried threading which stops the lag but then can't do anything with the audioclip. This has been asked a few times over the years but no answer yet. Here's the code:

```
 void Update()
{
    foreach(var d in devices){
        if (d.TryGetFeatureValue(CommonUsages.secondaryButton, out isPressed)){
            if (isPressed && !wasTalking)
                { 
                    wasTalking = true;
                    asource.PlayOneShot(walkietalkie);
                    //start_recording = new Thread(startRecording);
                    //start_recording.Start();
                    startRecording();  
                }
            else if (wasTalking && !isPressed){
                finishRecording();
                wasTalking = false;
            }
        }

private void startRecording(){
    
    recording = Microphone.Start(null, false, 30, freq);
    startRecordingTime = Time.time;
    yield return null;
}
```

Edit: I've removed the useless coroutine. Why the -1 to my question?

Comment: Just FYI your coroutine isn't actually doing anything .. it is completely executed within one frame anyway ;) .. also I'm pretty sure you can't do this async / in a thread since most of Unity API may only be called on the main thread

Comment: I'm aware :), just a long list of things I tried as I scrapped the bottom of the barrel in posibilites

Comment: 2 years and still no answer? Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: You need to start the microphone and let it run. No good for privacy and I've stopped using unity since the whole charging debacle.

Answer (score 0):

The primary way I reckon that you could alleviate the stutter is moving this work to another thread, which is notoriously hard with Unity.

A solution to this could be using or adapting another method of recording audio like [NAudio](https://github.com/naudio/NAudio).

Comment: I'm trying to keep this project as lean as possible. I'm thinking of starting the recording at start using a 30 second looped. Then getting when the user presses a button and when they let go. As long as it's less than 30 sec it should be fine

Comment: @jason Thinking more about your problem, the stuttering likely comes from a large amount of garbage collection happening, so do you reckon you could disable auto garbage collection and write your own script to manage it?

Comment: hmm, I don't think it's garbage collection as the stutter is caused when I start the microphone no matter how long the game has been running. Maybe it's creating the space in memory that's the problem, not accesssing it.

Comment: I meant that starting the microphone causes a large amount of garbage to be created. It is worth giving this an approach a go.

Answer (score 0):

Use coroutines.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;

public class TestMic : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] AudioSource self;
    public int samplerate = 44100;
    public int time = 10;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //Debug.Log(Microphone.devices);
        StartCoroutine("test");
    }
    IEnumerator test()
    {
        self.clip = Microphone.Start(null, true, time, samplerate);
        self.loop = true;
        self.Play();
        yield return null;
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I found using NAudio:

```
public int SampleRate = 44100;
public int Channels = 2;
public int BufferSize = 2048;
public string AsioDriver = "Focusrite USB ASIO";

private AsioOut asioOut;
private BufferedWaveProvider bufferedWaveProvider;
private BufferedSampleProvider bsp;

private void Start()
{
    WaveFormat waveFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat(SampleRate, Channels);
    bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(waveFormat);
    bsp = new BufferedSampleProvider(waveFormat);
    bsp.CurrentBuffer = new float[BufferSize * Channels];

    asioOut = new AsioOut(AsioDriver);
    asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback(bufferedWaveProvider, Channels, SampleRate);
    asioOut.AudioAvailable += OnAudioAvailable;
    asioOut.Play();

    Debug.Log(asioOut.DriverInputChannelCount);
}

private void OnAudioAvailable(object sender, AsioAudioAvailableEventArgs e)
{
    int samplesPerBuffer = e.SamplesPerBuffer * Channels;
    float[] buffer = new float[samplesPerBuffer];
    int count = e.GetAsInterleavedSamples(buffer);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i += Channels)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < Channels; j++)
        {
            bsp.CurrentBuffer[i + j] = buffer[i + j];
        }
    }

    int count2 = bsp.Read(buffer, 0, samplesPerBuffer);
    byte[] bufferBytes = new byte[count2 * 4];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, bufferBytes, 0, bufferBytes.Length);

    bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(bufferBytes, 0, bufferBytes.Length);
}
```

The following line is what initiates both the recording to start and the playback to happen simultaneously using the Focusrite USB ASIO driver:

```
asioOut.InitRecordAndPlayback
```

An ASIO driver is ideal in this situation, as it has much lower latency then using the windows sound drivers. I got the latency down to around 12ms using this method.